# Coffeescript trouble updating instance property

Tags: coffeescript

I'm having trouble accessing and updating what I *think* is an instance property in coffeescript.  I'm trying to update the @cart_total.  The first time I update the total, it works fine.  However, it only works the first time.  It seems the @cart_total is only updating once.

Here's the code:

```
class Cart 

  constructor: ()->
    @cart_total = 0.00 


  updateTotal: (amt)->
    @cart_total = @cart_total + amt


  this.updateTotal( @lineItem.total )
```

When I call updateTotal, it only seems to work the first time.  I am truly grateful for any help - thank you!

EDIT :

I call updateTotal from within the class.  I added the code above.

Comment: you dont have to write 0.00 in javascript as there is only one Number type, 0 is good enough. There is no 'instance variables' in javascript , since there is no classes. your function should work however we dont know how you call it.

Comment: How are you calling `updateTotal`? Perhaps a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ would help, you can use CoffeeScript there by choosing CoffeeScript under "Panels".

Comment: @camus - I appreciate the pointer about 0.  I updated the code to show how I call updateTotal

Comment: @mu - thank you!  I'm trying to learn how to use jsfiddle.new right now to provide a demo.  And updated how I call updateTotal.

Comment: That won't execute at all, `this` (which will be Cart) won't have an `updateTotal` method in that context: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dPT8Y/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're defining a class, any function calls should be within a method. Unless you're trying to create class methods or variables, but I don't believe that's what you're trying to accomplish here.

This might help:

```
class Cart 
    constructor:       -> @cart_total  = 0 
    updateTotal: (amt) -> @cart_total += amt
    getTotal:          -> @cart_total
    addTen:            -> @updateTotal 10

cart = new Cart

cart.updateTotal 9.50
console.log cart.getTotal()

cart.updateTotal 19.50
console.log cart.getTotal()

cart.addTen()
console.log cart.getTotal()​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Note:** The spacing is superfluous, but I liked how it looked. Good luck.